# How to get a Javascript array from php and save it in javascript array, in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

Javascript  Ajax call gets data from a table through PHP. It returns data as a Javascript array.

- When i do the  `console.log(this.responseText)` I get the following

```
[['ID','StudentName','Age'],['1','Student1','25'], ['2','Student2','24'], ['3','Student3','22'], ]
```

- When i type at console `this.responsetext`, i get the following

```
"[['ID','StudentName','Age'],['1','Student1','25'], ['2','Student2','24'], ['3','Student3','22'], ]"  ( quotes added )
```

- When i save this to a variable as following ,

```
myarray=this.responsetext
```

...it gets saved as string.

- When I save this to the variable as following (without quotes)

```
myarray=[['ID','StudentName','Age'],['1','Student1','25'], ['2','Student2','24'], ['3','Student3','22'], ]
```

...it is properly saved as an array.

I tried to remove the quotes(") by replace method, but it doesnt have any effect.

How to get a Javascript array from PHP and save it in javascript array, in javascript?

Comment: You need to encode the table data properly (as JSON). Use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for that. Next, use `const myarray = JSON.parse(this.responseText);` in your JS code.

Comment: Removing the quotes won't work because the string sent by the server doesn't contain them. It's the wrong approach anyway.

Comment: `It returns data as a Javascript array`...it can't do that, actually, because PHP doesn't have a JavaScript runtime. What it almost certainly returns is _JSON data_ whose syntax happens to _look like_ JavaScript code (and indeed is usable as a JS object literal in the right context), but is actually _a string of text_ which you need to _decode_ (or _parse_ in other words) into a usable program object.

Comment: Hi  Chris G. I am avoiding JSON because of unnecessary redundant data resulting in more traffic. why jSon for  a properly structured database table data ? This works perfectly when I include a JavaScript in the PHP file ( using <script> </script>). But the issue in Ajax call.

Comment: I have solved it. First of all the string should be made of doubl quotes instead of single. Then the comma at the end should not be there. Corrected my php code.  Then myarray=JSON.parse(this.responsetext) and got data in javascript array. Thanks Chris!